# How to auto complete / invoice order in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, api, invoice, virtual-products

I have **Magento webshop**, and I sell **virtual products**, with API all my products get send out automatically when the order is invoiced / completed.
 
It would be a lot easier if It could complete / invoice all orders automatically, is this possible?
It's my first time using Magento, so I'm a little blank at this point.

I'm using Magento 1.9.3.

Comment: You can use event Observer - `sales_order_save_after` - to catch the state of the order and then try to create invoice programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to create one small module that works with the observer.

Step 1 :

Insert below event to your config.xml

```
<events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <yourmodule_autoinvoice>
                    <class>yourmodule_autoinvoice/observer</class>
                    <method>autoInvoice</method>
                </yourmodule_autoinvoice>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```

then in observer event function use the logic to generate invoice and update order status.

```
class Yourmodule_Autoinvoice_Model_Observer
    {
        public function autoInvoice($observer) 
        {
                // loading placed order using observer.

                $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
                $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', array('eq'=>$order->getId()));
                $orders->getSelect()->limit(1);

                if ((int)$orders->count() !== 0) {
                    return $this;
                }

                try {
                        // checking the order can invoice or not.

                        if(!$order->canInvoice()) {
                            $order->addStatusHistoryComment('AutoInvoice: Order cannot be invoiced.', false);
                            $order->save();
                        } else {

                            $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();

                            // below capture method depends on your payment method.
                            // here I used CAPTURE_OFFLINE method.

                            $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
                            $invoice->register();

                            $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                                               ->addObject($invoice)
                                               ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
                            $transactionSave->save();

                            // Now its setting the status to processing. 
                            // for virtual products this might not required. 
                            // please test only with invoice generate code.

                            $invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
                            $order->addStatusHistoryComment(Mage::helper('yourmodule')->__('Auto Invoice generated.'), 
                                                                Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)->setIsCustomerNotified(true);
                            $invoice->sendEmail(true, '');
                            $order->save(); 
                        }

                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        $order->addStatusHistoryComment('AutoInvoice: Exception occurred during autoInvoice action. Exception message: '.$e->getMessage(), false);
                        $order->save();
                    }
            return $this;
        }
    }
```